# Input text and submit in one line

Tags: html, css, input

[image]

How to make this effect (cross-browsed) without using `float: left`?

I need to center this `form` so `float` attribute is wrong for me. Anybody can help?

I've made code as you can see below.

My code:

```css
footer input[type=text] {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 0;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid #df242b;
  background: #df242b url('../../../gfx/submit.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 38px;
  height: 37px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into default CSS frameworks like Bootstrap to help you? The style is easily changeable to your needs and does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, whilst keeping all browsers in check.

Comment: I use UIkit instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want it cross-browser and without using `float:left`, you can use `inline-block` with `vertical-align:top`

And to center, you need to apply `margin:0 auto` to `footer`  with some `width` instead

I made a few tweaks to your code.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* demo */
  background: lightgreen
}
footer {
  /*fix inlin block gap */
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 265px; /* 230px + 35px */
}
footer input {
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
footer input[type=text] {
  border: solid #efefef;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
footer input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid #df242b;
  background: #df242b url('//dummyimage.com/35x35') no-repeat center center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code without `float:left` actually works fine. Maybe you experience the line break on small sized screens. If it is the case, just add a piece of CSS for your footer like this example.

```css
footer {
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-align: center;
}

footer input[type=text] {
      border: 1px solid #efefef;
      border-right: 0;
      width: 230px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 18px;
      height: 35px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    footer input[type=submit] {
      border: 1px solid #df242b;
      background: #df242b url('../../../gfx/submit.jpg') no-repeat center center;
      color: #fff;
      width: 38px;
      height: 37px;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 18px;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<footer>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```html
<style>
body{margin:0;}
footer{
 width:100%;
 background:#ccc;
 height:250px;
}
.form{
 width:292px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
footer input[type=text] {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 0;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 37px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
footer input[type=submit] {
  border: 1px solid #df242b;
  background: #df242b;
  color: #fff;
  width: 38px;
  height: 37px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<footer>
  <div class="form">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="submit" value=">">
  </div>
</footer>
```